# How to change a file name in burned CD?

Tags: cd

I wrote 4 files to disc, other 3 is fine but one of them is missing a letter in file extension and it's not opening. I tried to format the CD from the disc but the format option is greyed out. Tried to edit as administer and it's not letting me do that either. When I google for solutions most of them are windows based so I really don't know what to do at this point. Any suggestions?

Edit: for second question, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, GNOME Version is 3.36.8.

For first question, I wrote files with brasero and it ejected the CD right after burning. My CD is probably not CDRW cause nothing writes on the top of it.

Second edit: Turning into a coaster for coffee mug doesn't sound bad.

Probably last edit: I didn't change the file's name, in original the name is correct. Brasero did it to make it compatible with Windows. The other three file is just as same with original files, only one file is missing a letter at the end. So it's not my mistake to remember later. Since it's a school project and nobody uses DVD's anymore, I probably won't use this future later, most of the computers don't even have CD slots these days.

Comment: If you closed the CD, you can no longer make changes as the media is now RO.  If you didn't close the CD after it's write, you'll be able to write elsewhere on the disk on the same machine that originally performed the write (it cannot change the data written unless CDRW, but some formats allow you to provide multiple copies of files & the later file is used *linked-list* type of access; ie. slow).  OS can't get around design limits of media.

Comment: CDs are write once read many times. That means once you write something in them, they cannot be changed. Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: Throw away the CD or turn it into a coaster for your coffee mug. Make a new CD.